# I broke an oath keeping something very important at stake

Tags: quran, allah

I'm a 15 year old Muslim who made an oath to not commit a sin but has done it more than once. I really want to repent but I'm not as healthy to be fasting and cant feed 10 people. I have kept something very important to my life at stake for breaking this oath. Please help me find a solution to this problem.